# How to make a div to represent a dotted line?

Tags: html, css

I have a barchart type made out of different divs. 
CSS:

```
.outer, .inner, .target {
      height: 14px;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .outer {
      background-color: #cccccc;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      font-size: 10px;
      line-height: 14px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    .inner {
      background-color: #66a3ff;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      width: calc(200 / 100 * 14.77px);
      color: white;
    }

    .target {
      background-color: transparent;
      width: 19px;
      position: absolute;
      border-right: 3px solid black;
      z-index: 2;
      color: black;
      text-align: right;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="outer"> 
        <div class="target" style="width: calc(<?php echo $bar_width; ?> / 100 * (<?php echo $target; ?> / <?php echo $base; ?> * 100))"></div>                   
        <div class="inner" style="width: calc(<?php echo $bar_width; ?> / 100 * (<?php echo $avg; ?> / <?php echo $base; ?> * 100))"></div>
    </div>
```

The black line represents the target line but I want to make it a dotted line, like in this case:
[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: change border from solid to dotted:  `border-right: 3px dotted black;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use css property border defining dotted background in it

```
.target {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 19px;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 3px dotted black; <--- change solid to dotted/dashed
  z-index: 2;
  color: black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a div for that and use below code:

```
.divclass{border-right:dotted 1px #333;}
```